# How to set xpath for crawler in Scrapy in python

Tags: python

how to set xpath for crawler (i am using Crapy library)? please help me

url: https://www.drugbank.vn/danh-sach/co-so-kinh-doanh

---

I did code below, but not get data

```
def parse(self, response):

    questions = Selector(response).xpath('//jhi-main/jhi-danh-sach')

    for question in questions:

        item = DrugbankItem()

        item['Name'] = question.xpath('div[@class="card border-0"]/div[@class="card-body"]/div[@class="table-responsive"]/table[@class="table table-striped table-bordered"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/text()').extract_first()
        yield item
```

---

thanks!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QfxE.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30qtq.png)

Comment: After inspecting the element, Right click over and select `copy xpath` to copy the exact xpath directly.

Comment: before using 'extract_first()' dry run and check if you are getting data fetching that 'xpath' you copied then apply 'extract_first()' in the next line.